# cygwin bash forward slash converted to backslash

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, filenames, slash

Cannot figure this one our or create a sample which can reproduce this.

Am trying using an external sh file to invoke the hadoop sh file

myfile.sh

```
# workingdir = /data1/some/path/lib
WORKINGDIR=`cygpath -p -w -m "$WORKINGDIR"`
# so the above in windows land is C:/some/path/lib
# HADOOPCMD essentially is a call to hadoop.sh
$HADOOPCMD jar $WORKINGDIR/myjar.jar
```

hadoop.sh

```
echo "$@" // still C:/some/path/lib
exec "$JAVA" $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS $CLASS "$@"
```

However when "$@" is expanded in cygwin the resultant path becomes C:\some\path\lib and then the hadoop.sh complaints that it cannot find the jar ... Not a valid JAR : C:\some\path\lib

However if I were to hardcode the path in myfile.sh ; it works

```
$HADOOPCMD jar C:/some/path/lib/myjar.jar
```

Question

1. why does the exec command's "$@" change the / to \ in the WORKINGDIR variable ?
2. why does the hardcoded path work ?
3. how to get this to work with variable substituion ?

Comment: hmm .. i think i got it to work by quoting the $WORKINGDIR so the command is $HADOOPCMD jar "$WORKINGDIR"/myjar.jar

Comment: General rule of thumb is "always quote your variable expansions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the variable works `"$WORKINGDIR"/myjar.jar`